# Extension of compatible almost complex structures from a closed set

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, symplectic-geometry, almost-complex

Suppose that $(M,\omega)$ is a symplectic manifold, and $N \subset M$ is a closed submanifold of $M$. If $J_N: TM|_N \rightarrow TM|_N$ is an $\omega$-compatible almost complex structure, defined on $N$, is it always possible to extend $J_N$ to a globally defined $\omega$-compatible almost complex structure?

I feel like this should be the case, since for any vector space $(V,\sigma)$, the space of $\sigma$-compatible almost complex structures is contractible, and so the bundle over $M$ whose fiber at $p$ is the space of $\omega_p$-compatible complex structures of $T_pM$ has contractible fibers, and so every partially-defined section on nice enough closed sets  should extend by general homotopy theoretic arguments, but I confess that I'm not comfortable with these sorts of arguments yet, so it would be nice if someone could tell me if something like this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed the case that a compatible/tame almost complex structure defined on an appropriate subspace of a symplectic manifold extends to a compatible/tame almost complex structure over the whole manifold, essentially for the reason you contemplate. (An instance of this result is the object of Exercise 2.2.19 in Chris Wendl's [Lectures on Holomorphic Curves in Symplectic and Contact Geometry](https://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/%7Ewendl/pub/jhol_bookv33.pdf), when the subspace is some open heighborhood of a closed subset of the symplectic manifold.)

To fix ideas, let's consider the situation for compatible structures; the case of tame structures follows the same reasoning. Given a symplectic manifold $(M, \omega)$, consider the fiber bundle $\pi : E := J(M, \omega) \to M$ whose fiber $E_m$ consists in the complex structures on $T_m M$ which are compatible with $\omega_m$. Using Darboux's theorem, one can show that this is indeed a fiber bundle in the sense given *e.g.* on pages 376-377 of Allen Hatcher's [Algebraic Topology](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf). Hence Proposition 4.48 in Hatcher proves that $\pi$ has the homotopy lifting property with respect to any $CW$-pair $(X, A)$ (see p. 376 for a definition), in particular when $X = M$ and $A$ is some $CW$-subspace of $M$, *e.g.* when $A = N$ is an embedded closed submanifold.

Now, a compatible almost complex structure on $A$ is a section $J_A$ of $\pi$ over $A$. Moreover, Theorem 2.2.8 in Wendl shows that the space of compatible almost complex structures on $M$, *i.e.* of global sections of $\pi$, is nonempty and contractible; In fact, it follows from the proof that this contraction occurs fiberwise. This implies that there exist a global compatible almost complex structure $J'$ on $M$ and a fiber-preserving homotopy from $J_A$ to $J'|_A$ over $A$ (and thus a fiber-preserving homotopy from $J'|_A$ to $J_A$). Applying the homotopy lifting property of $\pi$ with respect to $(M, A)$ yields a global section $J$ of $\pi$ such that $J|_A = J_A$.